# Removing table's border inside tfoot and thead

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

I would like to remove `border` inside the `tfoot` and `thead` area when printing. When the table's row were breaked into new page, the border continues to show even inside the `tfoot` and also `thead` area. This is the screenshot of the issue:

[image]

My Code :

```css
@media print {
  .report-container {
    page-break-after: always;
  }
  thead.report-header {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
  tfoot.report-footer {
    display: table-footer-group;
    border: none;
  }
  #spacer {
    height: 230px;
  }
  #footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    border: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="report-container" width="100%" style="" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
  <thead class="report-header">
    <tr>
      <td width="" align="left">
        <?php if ($so_invoice_report_row['has_header_footer']) { echo html_entity_decode($rowHeaderFooter['header_content']); } else {} ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot class="report-footer">
    <tr>
      <td width="" align="left" id="spacer"></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php
          //include 'table_content.php';
        ?>
        <table border=1 style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <?php
        for($i=0; $i<=100;$i++) {
         echo '<tr><td>';
         echo "Column " . $i . '</td><td> Column2 ';
         echo '</td></tr>';
        }
        ?>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="footer">
  <?php if ($so_invoice_report_row['has_header_footer']) { echo html_entity_decode($rowHeaderFooter['footer_content']); } else {} ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed `position: fixed; bottom: 0;` from `#footer` in your CSS style sheet as below and apply a height value for your footer.

```
@media print {
  .report-container {
    page-break-after: always;
  }
  thead.report-header {
    display: table-header-group;
    background-color:red;
  }
  tfoot.report-footer {
    display: table-footer-group;
    border: none;
    background-color:green;
  }
  tbody {
    background-color:blue;
  }
  #spacer {
    margin-bottom: 150px;
  }
  #footer {
    border: none;
  }
} 




<table class="report-container" width="100%" style="" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
  <thead class="report-header">
    <tr>
      <th width="" align="left">
        <?php if ($so_invoice_report_row['has_header_footer']) { echo html_entity_decode($rowHeaderFooter['header_content']); } else {} ?>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot class="report-footer" id="spacer">
    <tr>
      <td><?php if ($so_invoice_report_row['has_header_footer']) { echo html_entity_decode($rowHeaderFooter['footer_content']); } else {} ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><?php
          include 'table_content.php';
        ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This will work for you. Try it. 
Let me know if any problem is raised.

Comment: Tried as per suggested, but the `div` footer is now not repeating on each page. It only display on top of the third page(this is the last page, the table only until page 2)

Comment: I didn't notice before. your HTML code format is wrong. why don't you put <div id="footer"> inside your <tfoot>?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Use that HTML code and let me know what is your result is. It is bit hard resolve this problem without seeing code.

Comment: By removing the `position: fixed; bottom: 0;` the last page's footer is placed right below the last element of the `tbody`. That's why I added the div with footer ID. Tested using your latest code but the border still visible on `tfoot` and `thead` area. BTW, I'm using Chrome to test this.

Comment: Still the same, I guest I need to look into the table_content.php file if it is what causing the issue. As currently there are many nested table inside it(the file was created long ago by someone else, so I don't really know the formatting)

Comment: I replaced the include_content.php with testing `for` loop above. Could you try it on your local and see if you encounter the same issue as mine? As I couldn't solve this issue even when using your updated code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't really reproduce your result... Could you please post a bit of generated html that shows the problem (I mean, actually containing table data instead of -stuff).

BUT if I get you right, you're trying to keep the marked space free for the corporate header and footer already contained on the paper you're using. In that case, I have a workaround for you

1. Add white (meaning: `background: white;`) divs the desired size with fixed position and a higher z-index at the top and the bottom of your html page containing your additional header data *
2. Add blank divs with relative positioning and the size of your header/footer before and after your html page content, so the whole content won't "go under" the other header/footer elements (I thought using padding should also work but here it didn't)
3. Leave the thead and tfooter empty - just size it so it won't "go under" the other header/footer elements

Test it.

*) Note: apparently (at least on Opera 54.0) a white background colour is never ignored, but if your header/footer seems to be transparent instead of white when printing, look for the option to "print background images"

Comment: I have a requirement to add header and footer into current templates(hence the use of `include 'table_content.php';`). So, I use the `thead` and `tfoot` tag to achieve this, but the problem is when the data doesn't fit into 1 page.. the horizontal border is visible within `tfoot` and `thead` area(the area which I highlighted in red).

Comment: Do you have any example code to solve this issue? My header and footer area still having the table border.

Comment: Sure. Or maybe, actually. Can you please post a html snippet where the <php> tags are replaced with actual content? I will then check if I can get my suggested workaround working